# Laravel route & crwling issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, robots.txt

We have a production marketing app with routes like

/tools/it-management

and

/solution/product-comparison

etc..

The issue is that the MOZ and Google crawler are indexing /tools and /solution when those aren't directories nor index pages exist. So in return we are getting a bunch of 404 error.

Can anyone suggest a good away to Disallow: /tools without affecting the route views that use /tools as the example above?

Comment: Try adding or editing robots file with disallow of this folder: https://thesearchguru.com/add-robots-txt-file/

Comment: Just to be clear, it is not a folder, just route to Laravel view. There is no physical directory. The other issue is that under /tools we have about 15 pages. Disallowing /tools won't disallow the routes?

adding Disallow: /tool wont affect all the

Comment: Even a virtual folder can be disallowed I think.. You could also detect user agent from request headers to do something in code.. For testing there is a nice Chrome adding to switch user agents and pretend to be Google bot..